# How do I put this dropdown menu below header in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu

I created a dropdown menu via this site http://www.menucool.com/drop-down-menu . The final code zip file has a .html file , .css file and a .js file . How to I place this under header ?

Answer (score 0):

You should open header.php file of your theme, then add these tags for include css (for example style.css) and js file (for example script.js) between [do_action( 'genesis_meta' );] e [wp_head();] of your theme:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/script.js">
```

and copy and paste html code first of this row [genesis_structural_wrap( 'site-inner' );] (I believe).

Remember to change the path of your css and js file where you copy the files.

Enjoy your code.

Comment: Should I just copy the .css and .js file in theme folder ( wp-content\themes\genesis ). I am using Genesis .

Comment: Ok, but use the wp funtion get_template_directory_uri() for print the path to theme folder. I have edited my post.

Comment: Show my post review, I hope there is correct. Save a backup copy of your header.php for restore.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use this menu as a editable wordpress menu, you should use

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>
```

in  your html codes.
[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

Comment: I have no coding knowledge :(

Comment: use Magicianred answer.